# Elastic Watcher Format Date

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-watcher

I have a watcher set up in elastic search and would like to send the timestamp as one of the fields in my email.  Currently when the email is sent the time is UTC time.  Is it possible to format this value to display the time in the local time zone?

UPDATE: Added current config

```
{
  "trigger": {
    "schedule": {
      "interval": "24h"
    }
  },
  "input": {
    "search": {
      "request": {
        "search_type": "query_then_fetch",
        "indices": [
          "dev*"
        ],
        "rest_total_hits_as_int": true,
        "body": {
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "match_phrase": {
                    "messageTemplate": "Could not decompress file {FileName} for task: {TaskId}"
                  }
                }
              ],
              "filter": {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "range": {
                        "@timestamp": {
                          "gte": "now-24h",
                          "lte": "now"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "task_name": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "fields.TaskName.keyword"
              },
              "aggregations": {
                "reason": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "fields.ExceptionMessage.keyword"
                  },
                  "aggregations": {
                    "file_name": {
                      "terms": {
                        "field": "fields.FileName.keyword"
                      },
                      "aggregations": {
                        "fail_time": {
                          "date_histogram": {
                            "field": "@timestamp",
                            "calendar_interval": "1s",
                            "format": "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss a"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "condition": {
    "compare": {
      "ctx.payload.hits.total": {
        "gte": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "actions": {
    "email_users": {
      "email": {
        "profile": "standard",
        "to": [
          "j@somedomain.com"
        ],
        "subject": "DEV: Failed to Decompress File",
        "body": {
          "html": "<p>The following files could not be decompressed/unzipped. <div><ul>{{#ctx.payload.aggregations.task_name.buckets}}<li>There were {{#doc_count}}{{.}}{{/doc_count}} files that could not be decompressed/unzipped for {{#key}}{{.}}{{/key}}.<ul>{{#reason.buckets}}<li>{{#doc_count}}{{.}}{{/doc_count}} items failed for reason: {{#key}}{{.}}{{/key}}<ul>{{#file_name.buckets}}<li>{{#key}}{{.}}{{/key}} failed at {{#fail_time.buckets.0.key_as_string}}{{.}}{{/fail_time.buckets.0.key_as_string}}</li>{{/file_name.buckets}}</ul></li>{{/reason.buckets}}</ul></li>{{/ctx.payload.aggregations.task_name.buckets}}</ul></div><p>These files were sent to quarantine</p>"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Elastic and Kibana are new to me so there may be better ways to perform this search and aggregation.  If so, I am open to suggestions.

Comment: Please share the configuration of the watcher that you have so far.

Comment: I was able to get the correct format by adding `"time_zone": "America/Chicago"` to my date_histogram aggregation